# Why is $\deg (P) \le n $?

Tags: polynomials, linear-transformations

Let $T:V \rightarrow V$ be a linear operator on an $n$ dimensional vector space $V$. If $p$ is the minimal polynomial for $T$. Is it true that $deg (p) \le n$? Can this be proven without knowing that $p \mid f $ where $f$ is the characteristic polynomial

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $q$ be the characteristic polynomial, we know that the degree of $q$ is $n$.

$p$ is the monic polynomial satisfying $p(T)=0$ with the least degree.

Suppose not, that is $deg(p)>n$. Since $q$ is a monic polynomail with $q(T)=0$, $q$ violates minimality of $p$, which is a contradiction.

Hence $deg(q) \leq n$.